# How to filter file by name in Windows 7 explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-filter

I know that I can search for file in the search box on the top right corner of the explorer; how ever, I would like to filter file and folder name by a string. For example: I would like to find file with the suffix `.exe` in current, but I don't want to list all the `.exe` files in sub-folders - I only want to filter by file name, not find in all the dirs.

Is that possible? or is there any third party software can do this?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks, that's cool command line. How can I copy/cut/delete/rename after this filter? Only list is not enough.

Comment: If you need basic windows command line tutorials, there's about [a million of them online](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html). ;) Copy = `copy`, Delete = `del`, Rename = `ren`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In Explorer:

Sort by "Type" column, and look for "Application".

By Command prompt, or PowerShell prompt:

```
cd \your\folder\
dir *.exe
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to say, this is a valid solution to part of the problem. This solved my `.exe` example. How about filter files with string `0701` in it?

Comment: "How about filter files with string 0701 in it?" Look for "0701 File" instead of "Application".  And/or `dir *.0701` from a command prompt. :)